# how do you find a derivative of $y=1-\cos(x)\sin(x)$

Tags: calculus

The question asks to find the derivative of the function $1-\cos(x)\sin(x)$, and I thought maybe using some derivative rules I could, but I don't know where to start.

Comment: Apply the rules: how to differentiate $f-g$, constant, then $f\cdot g$, finally you also need $\sin'=\cos$ and $\cos'=-\sin$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you familiar with the product rule?
$$
f(x)=u(x)v(x)\\
f'(x)=u'(x)v(x) + u(x)v'(x)
$$
In your case $u(x)=\cos(x), \ v(x)=\sin(x)$.

EDIT Sorry again for the typos, Here's what you should do. The derivative of constant is always 0, derivative of $-h(x)$ is $-h'(x)$, the derivative of a product of functions is above, the derivative of $\cos'(x)=- \sin(x), \ \sin'(x)=\cos(x)$

Can you handle it now?

EDIT 2: Sorry for doing it again, there is a different way of solving the problem if you notice that

$$
-\cos(x) \sin(x) = -\frac{2}{2}\cos(x) \sin(x)=-\frac{1}{2}\sin(2x) 
$$
and then use the chain rule:
$\frac{du(v(x))}{dx} = u'(v(x))v'(x)$ and then use the derivative of the sin function

EDIT 3: OK here is the solution:
$$
f'(x)=(-\cos(x)\sin(x))'_{x}=(-\frac{1}{2}\sin(2x))'_{x}=-\frac{1}{2}(2x)'_{x}\cos(2x)=-\cos(2x)
$$

Comment: you mean the product rule

Comment: @Alex : that is the product rule.  We don't want to confuse the OP.  Also, you can use  "\sin" and "\cos".

Comment: Well, yes, you can rewrite it using $\sin(2x) = 2\sin(x)\cos(x)$

Comment: Sorry for the typo, will update it now

Comment: I am not sure how you got the 2 in there?

Comment: added the solution

Comment: No, the derivative of a constant is 0, so it just 'disappears', then I rewrite $- \sin x \cos x = -\frac{2}{2}\sin x \cos x=-\frac{1}{2} \sin(2x)$. Do you know of expansion of sinus of double angle?

Comment: How did you get -2/2

Comment: You have $- \cos x \sin x  = -1 \cdot \cos x \sin x = -\frac{2}{2} \cdot \cos x \sin x$

Comment: Got it, so then how did you end up with (-1/2)sin(2x)??

Comment: It is called sinus of double angle, $\sin 2 x = 2 \sin x \cos x$

Comment: K, so you just applied that to?

Comment: Yes, I just rewrote the expression in your problem and then found the derivative, see EDIT2 in my answer

Comment: I think I get where your going with this. Thank you so much for explaining it through!!

Answer (score 2):

Using the well known trigonometric identity,

$$\sin(2x)=2\sin(x)\cos(x)$$

We can say that,

$$y=1-\sin(x)\cos(x)=1-\frac{2\sin(x)\cos(x)}{2}=1-\frac{\sin(2x)}{2}$$

and the derivative would be:

$$y'=0-\frac{2\cos(2x)}{2}=-\cos(2x)$$

Comment: Upvoted for greatness. However, it won't help him in the long run because if he's asking this he clearly doesn't know about the product rule.

Answer (score 0):

$$(1 - \sin(x)\cos(x))'  = \left(1 - \frac12 \sin(2x)\right)' = -\cos(2x).$$ Implicitly, I used  the [chain rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) here, letting $f(x) = \sin(x)$ and $ g(x) = 2x$.

Comment: Where did you get the -(1/2)sin(2x)??

Comment: Sorry, I dont know the chain rule. But thank you for helping.

Comment: By using $\sin(2x) = 2\sin(x)\cos(x).$

Comment: Got it, thanks!